# PHP Cookies not being set in WAMP

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have two scripts, one for processing a login and one for registering a login, they both create a sessiod id and insert it into both a cookie and a database. The DB insert works just fine, however, the cookies are not set:

login:

```
//...Stuff...
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dm_users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {
        header("Location: denied.php?u");
        die();
    }
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $brought = $r['password'];
    }
    if (PassHash::check_password($brought, $password)) {  
        if($remember == 1) {
            $time = time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        } else {
            $time = 0;
        }
        $val = uniqid() . time();
        setcookie("dmsesid",$val,$time);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO dm_sessions (username,sesid,`timestamp`) VALUES ('$username','$val',now())";
        $r = mysql_query($sql);
        $sql2 = "UPDATE dm_users set lastlogin = NOW() WHERE username = '$username'";
        $r2 = mysql_query($sql2);
        header('Location: ../characters.php');
    } else {  
        //...More stuff...
```

Register process works in much the same way, but only with the $time = 0; option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @DevZer0 the session id I'm inserting isn't a PHP session id, it's a unique id that relates a users computer to the mysql sessions table. The cookie value is later checked against the sessions table (among other things) to determine if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting ? Are you sending any data (for example HTML) before setting the cookie ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to set the path for the cookie

```
setcookie("dmsesid",$val,$time, '/');
```

From PHP manual:

The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain . If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain . The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.